# Scrapy. How to navigate, select and submit form

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to make a bot to simulate some human behaviors, and I got some instructions about scrapy to login at a page like nike.com.br, but once I need to select some buttons and submit some forms I was not able to find how.

Can anyone help me on it?

for example, after the login, I need to chose the size of the product and click at add to the cart, that is some way to do it using scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer you question because it's too generic, and this probably will have different solutions for different pages.

Generally speaking you need to check what the page is doing when you click to submit the form. Most likely a POST request, so you will need to mimic that POST request with scrapy (check [FormRequest](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects)).

Same logic applies to add item to the card.

I think the best way to approach that is to use the browser's network tool. In scrapy docs there are a few tips about using it for similar purpose ([here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html?highlight=network%20tools#the-network-tool)).